# If Else statement in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have "Text1" in A1 and I want to say

if a1= "text1" then "text2" 
else "text1"

How do I write this in Apps Script from scratch? I am lost with defining my variables so basically the beginning

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I did try, it's all very overwhelming. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Sounds like you might back out and do some fundamental programming logic review. You'll need to understand the difference between assignment and comparison, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple implementation in App Script:

```
 function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Gets the active spreadsheet. 
  var range = ss.getRange('A1'); //Reference A1 Notation see references below
  var value = range.getValue(); //Gets the cell value and assigned it to the variable
  if(value == 'Text1'){
    range.setValue('Text2') //Sets the value on the range 
  }
  else{
    range.setValue('Text1')
  }
}
```

This should get you started on your journey to app script.

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getValue()

Answer (score 2):

Logical equal is `==`.

```
let value = null;
if{ a1 == "text1" }
  value = "text2"
}
else {
  value = "text1" }
}
```

Another easier way to do this is

```
let value = a1 == "text1" ? "text2" : "text1";
```

Reference

- [if else](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- [comparison operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)